# Second display problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

Preface: I have a laptop with **Ubuntu 16.04 / Windows 10** in dualboot and 2 external displays, one with VGA input, and another with HDMI.

Various times I'm using HDMI display as the second on Windows or Ubuntu, and everything is fine.

When I connect VGA display using Windows, all is well too. 
But the problem is connecting VGA display with Ubuntu,so, I can use just internal laptop screen or external VGA screen, or even mirror video on both screens, but when I try to use extend mode, all that I see is a black screen on one or another display :(

P.S. My graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 7600m, I'm using open source Radeon driver. 
Another weird thing: internal display resolution is 1366x768 and external VGA is 1280x1024. When I set 1024x768 instead of usual 1280x1024, it works properly. But using any other resolution leads to black screen.

`xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2390 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
        eDP connected primary 1366x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
           1366x768      59.93*+
           1280x720      59.86  
           1152x768      59.78  
           1024x768      59.92  
           800x600       59.86  
           848x480       59.66  
           720x480       59.71  
           640x480       59.38  
        VGA-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
           1280x1024     60.02 +  75.02  
           1280x960      60.00  
           1152x864      75.00  
           1024x768      75.08*   70.07    60.00  
           832x624       74.55  
           800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
           640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
           720x400       70.08  
        HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto   AMD Radeon HD 7600m. Using open source Radeon driver, since proprietary fgrlx is deprecated at 16.04

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto 
Another weird thing: internal display resolution is 1366x768 and external VGA is 1280x1024.  When I set 1024x768 instead of usual 1280x1024, it works properly. But using any other resolution leads to black screen.  Maybe it'll help to identify the problem...

Comment: That is relevant information, please include it in the question. Also include the output of `xrandr`. Finally, can you also try the proprietary driver (even if deprecated) for a moment and report if it makes any difference?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I've added it to the question, including `xrandr` output. As for proprietary driver,  I've found info that even if I want, I couldn't install it, since the driver does not support Xorg 1.18 that ships in Xenial.

Comment: @JacobVlijm shouldn't it be `1280` since the desired resolution is that one?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto aarrrgh, you are right of course, I blindly took the resolution of xrandr... will re- comment :) Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run from a terminal :  `xrandr output VGA-0 --pos 0x0 --output eDP --pos 1280x0`? (with VGA-0 set to 1280x1024, and the eDP connected)

Comment: @JacobVlijm  It's amazing! I've successfully changed resolution to native after that. But what's the magic? Does it change screens positions relative to each other?

Comment: Hi @Uroboros, posted my answer. please mention if you manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What often works

With `VGA-0` set to `1280x1024` and `eDP` connected. run the command (from a terminal):

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --pos 0x0 --output eDP --pos 1280x0
```

which does what should happen automatically after you connected the second screen. The command top- aligns both screens, with `eDP` at 1280 from the top-left of `VGA-0`.

If this works, as a workaround, add the command to a shortcut key which you can press after connecting the second screen. Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --pos 0x0 --output eDP --pos 1280x0
```

#### What is the issue?

Graphics drivers seem to be the bottle-neck in many minor incompatibilities. Also in many cases, we can solve it with a small workaround like above.

The exact reason for your issue might be a timing issue, the screen and the driver do not " recognize each other" in time, so the procedure breaks.

Important part is that we can subsequently persuade the system to do the setup with an `xrandr` command :).

Comment: Comprehensive answer, just need small syntax fix: `--output...`

Comment: @Uroboros aarrgh, fixed. Did it by heart. Thanks!